# iOSのcustom keyboardで、画面解像度変更に対応したサイズ変換の実装ができません。

Tags: swift, ios

iOS用のcustom keyboardを開発しているのですが、
機種ごとの解像度への自動対応の仕組みで苦慮しています。

viewWillAppear内で

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
```

で画面サイズを取得して、
その画面サイズから、キーボードの表示領域と、キーのwidthなどを計算で算出し、
Interface Builderを使わずにキーボードを描画させていますが、
新しいアプリでは大丈夫でも、
少し昔のアプリでキーボードが表示されると、
auto-scalingでサイズ拡大（おそらく約1.17倍）されてしまうことがあり、
以下の画像のように、キーボードの右側が画面から溢れて、表示されないキーが生じてしまいます。

[image: 古いアプリでキーボードが拡大され、非表示領域ができてしまう。左が正しい表示。右が古いアプリで拡大表示への対応ができていない表示。]

厄介なのは自動拡大された場合でも、上記screenSizeのwidthを取得すると、例えばiPhone6のサイズに合わせて375という値を返してきて、もともとの画面幅の320を返してくれないことです。
（320を返してくれれば、簡単に計算し直せるのですが。）

そこで質問ですが、
auto-scalingする前の実際の画像解像度を取得する方法はありますでしょうか。
viewDidLoad内でやってもダメでした。
もしくは、他に良い解決方法がありますでしょうか。
例えば、constraintsをほぼ使っていないので、それを使えば解決できるでしょうか。
（現状、ほぼ全てプログラム的に表示させており、constraintsを使っていません）

初歩的な質問かもしれず恐縮ですが、
お分かりの方がおられれば、ご教授いただけると幸いです。

大まかな実装は、以下のような感じのコードです。

```
    //画面サイズ取得
    myAppFrameSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    print(myAppFrameSize!.width)

    screenWidth = myAppFrameSize!.width
    screenHeight = myAppFrameSize!.height

    isPortlait = screenWidth > screenHeight ? false : true //画面方向の確認
    isIPad = screenWidth > 900 ? true:false

    if(isIPad){
        keyWidth = 100
    }else if(screenWidth < 900 && screenWidth > 370){
        keyWidth = 55
    }else{
        keyWidth = 48
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` 内で `self.view.bounds` を参照してはいかがでしょうか。

何度か呼ばれる内、最初(`viewDidLoad` や `viewWillAppear` が呼ばれる頃)は自動拡大される前のサイズ(width=375)になるかと思いますが、 `viewDidAppear` が呼ばれる直前には自動拡大後のサイズ(width=320)が取れるようになるはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！ご回答いただいていたことに気づいておりませんでした。失礼致しました。
早速試してみます。